# My custom ringtone plays with stuttering, what may be the problem?

Tags: ringtone

After some time (may be it's related to the update to 4.4.x) my custom call ringtone (a .flac file) started to stutter permanently and always.

I can hear it even while choosing it in a system settings. But playing the file with another player works fine.

What can be the problem?

---

Model: Nexus 4 
Version: 4.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in Android 4.4 which causes flac files to pop and stutter.

AndroidPolice has an [article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/01/08/bug-watch-flac-audio-files-are-popping-and-stuttering-on-android-4-4-a-fix-is-coming/) on it, there is a fix that has been committed (but not released) according to this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62562). It should be fixed in the next release (although when that'll be is anyone's guess)

> Since the problem exists in Android's native flac codec, which is used
>   by most of the music players available, finding an alternative app
>   with its own custom implementation will easily solve the issue.